# Creating a CSV file with PHP, text doesn't go into seperate rows

Tags: php, csv

[My CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX04P.jpg) doesnt seperate the strings into rows, but into commas. i have looked into the fputcsv documentation but found nothing
My code:

```
//Header
        $headers = array("Name", "Website");

        //Array of data
        $csvinput = array(
            array(
                "name" => "John Morris",
                "website" => "http://www.test.de",
            ),
            array(
                "name" => "Peter Pan",
                "website" => "http://www.test2.de",
            ),
        );

        //Open/Create the file
        $fh = fopen(plugin_dir_path(__DIR__)."wp-markenbuero/test.csv", 'w');

        //Create the headers
        fputcsv($fh, $headers);

        //Data insert
        foreach($csvinput as $fields){
            fputcsv($fh, $fields);
        }

        //Close file
        fclose($fh);
```

Did i miss something?

Comment: the file is correct just open the file as csv in your viewer. or try to open with google spreadsheet it will automatically display the website in B column

Comment: Please post the result of the actual CSV-file instead of a screen shot of an application that just uses the data.

Comment: Set "Comma" as delimiters in the setting of excel.

Comment: A `csv` is nominally "comma separated values", which means columns are separated by commas, rows are separated by newlines. Your CSV file is correct, you just need to tell Excel which character (comma) to use for the column separator.

Comment: Yes thank you guys, i changed from comma to semicolon and now it works just fine

Comment: Microsoft Excel has a bug/feature by which it'll use the list separator character defined by the internationalisation settings of the local PC rather than, well, commas. They probably think it's fine because, as American users, they cannot see the difference :)

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my understanding the arrays included in the $csvinput array should not be associative:

$csvinput = array(
            array(
                "John Morris","http://www.test.de"
            ),
            array(
                "Peter Pan","http://www.test2.de"
            )
        );

Comment: As far as I know, it's completely valid to use an associative array

Comment: An associated array is fine. It just won't put the keys into the file.